# Unable to print the document using Java printer Services(JPS)

Tags: java

I have implemented a program, to print the document to the specific printer using IP address, printer name and running fine with out any errors and exception. A printer job is being sent from java, I am able to see this on my local printer print pool, but the page is not printing on printer.

```
URI myURI=null;
FileInputStream psStream=null;
try   {
    psStream = new FileInputStream("sample.doc");
}
catch ( FileNotFoundException e )   {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
DocFlavor psInFormat = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.GIF;
Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc( psStream, psInFormat, null );
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet(); 
PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices( psInFormat, aset);
if ( services.length > 0 ) {
    DocPrintJob job = services[0].createPrintJob();         
    try {
        job.print( myDoc, aset);
    }
    catch ( PrintException e ){
    }
}
```

Could you please help me out on this?

Thanks,
Srikanth Chilukuri

---

I found the problem.

```
psStream = new FileInputStream("sample.doc");
```

The above statement creating problem. Because It is MS Word Application, So unable to read the file using File Input Stream.

I am using POI jar and reading the doc.

```
POIFSFileSystem psStream = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(filesname));
Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc( psStream, psInFormat, null );
```

But Doc API is not supporing got IllegalArgumentException

```
Exception in thread "Main Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: data is not of declared type
    at javax.print.SimpleDoc.<init>(SimpleDoc.java:82)
    at com.src.print.TestPrint2.main(TestPrint2.java:67)
```

Could you please help me out on this.

Comment: It might not solve your problem, but you should not ignore your `PrintException` silently.

Answer (score 0):

Java Print Services allow you to "draw" pages like Swing and then send the result to a printer.  It does not have knowledge of Word formats or HTML pages or similar.

Therefore you need a module which knows how to draw the contents of a doc-file to a printer to do this.  I do not personally have experience with such a module.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response

I guess you are talking about the AWT print. This is different from Java Print Service. You can have have preformatted text data printed using a variety of options using Java Print Service(JPS)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jps/spec/docflavor.fm1.html#998469

The problem comes in when the file is encoded using UTF-8 and you try to print this using JPS
if its a normal ASCII file. it gets printed correctly